# Include nodejs modules from other folder to the project folder

Tags: node.js, module, directory

I've just started learning nodejs. I have my 'upper-case' module installed in C:\Users\User_name\node_modules directory and my nodejs project folder is in C:\wamp64\www.

So how can I write require() so that the 'upper-case' can be used in the project file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is from the npm. I've installed it from cmd using the command 'npm install upper-case'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't know the module system yet. It's a bad practice to install things globally (npm i -g package) or in an other directory.

Create a package.json in the base directory of your project (C:\wamp64\www) with "npm init" and install modules their (call "npm i module-name" in this directory). (Open the command line from this directory using the context menu or "cd" into it). Then you can simply use require('module-name')